# Problems fetching OS updates (App center seemingly not working the right way...)

Tags: apps, appcenter

I'm fairly new to Elementary, so I'm still having problems every once in a while.

It's been a couple of weeks since I downloaded OS updates the last time, but the App center has ceased to work properly ever since...

Here's the notification that comes out every time I try to fetch new updates:

E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons is not (yet) available (Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.elementary.io_appcenter_dists_xenial_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 104.28.4.44 80])

Can anybody help me to fix the bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got this error resolved by running

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

[source](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/appcenter-not-working.2327/)

Answer (score 0):

Going based just off of your error message. The contents of that directory are only partially downloaded. [This could be due to apt possibly being interrupted at some point during its last run]

(**warning:** *this can be a very dangerous command if not typed exactly as specified*)

This should fix your problem:

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`

and then simply try running:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Let me know if this helps :)