# Unable to use appcenter repository (hash-mismatch)

Tags: release-juno, appcenter, repositories

This is a fresh install of juno, and since day one i am unable to use the appcenter or update via apt

this is the error:

```
Err:3 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                                                     
  La suma hash difiere
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:158488 [weak]
   - SHA256:c14dc09acc3a9b1614b13ed15231c02372112d4cac9e1b9f6c583621e76bd104
   - SHA1:0a16db9283e0c7bf9f082a1c74cdde454dde0eae [weak]
   - MD5Sum:17a945b577cf02845d9306269767dbe8 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:40d03f1e2a9d5dd112a6f1242858d7d45c4a9de249b228477a436d8c78309ff1
   - SHA1:c08b5f6cba992cb34e09c0faba9b21fe39036fce [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4b8cadc3c304e9fee6c02ebffc792e40 [weak]
   - Filesize:158488 [weak]
```

The problem persist since yesterday.

So far i have tried:
[Problems fetching OS updates (App center seemingly not working the right way...)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15227/problems-fetching-os-updates-app-center-seemingly-not-working-the-right-way)
[Repository problems, on a new installed Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16913/repository-problems-on-a-new-installed-juno)
[Unable to update the system using apt](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/unable-to-update-the-system-using-apt)

Comment: Can you please take a look at - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18668/hash-sum-mismatch-error-on-update/18672#18672

Comment: The problem persist, please notice that appcenter does not have mirrors to alternate to, therefor i am stuck with the error.

Comment: Please look at the answer i linked and execute those commands suggested by @Hasan. Let me what you see, screenshots maybe